# Delay a single method for snake game c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using SwinGame to develop a snake game. The method MoveForward handles the movement of the snake. The problem that I have now is that i am unable to delay that particular method so that the snake will be moving at a constant slow speed.

Here are the codes in the Main:

```
using System;
using SwinGameSDK;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MyGame
{
    public class GameMain
    {

    public static void Main ()
    {

        //Open the game window
        SwinGame.OpenGraphicsWindow ("GameMain", 800, 600);
        SwinGame.ShowSwinGameSplashScreen ();

        Snake snake = new Snake ();


        //Run the game loop
        while (false == SwinGame.WindowCloseRequested ()) {
            //Fetch the next batch of UI interaction
            SwinGame.ProcessEvents ();

            //Clear the screen and draw the framerate
            SwinGame.ClearScreen (Color.White);

            SwinGame.DrawFramerate (0, 0);

            // Has to go after ClearScreen and NOT before refreshscreen

            snake.Draw ();

            Task.Delay (1000).ContinueWith (t => snake.MoveForward ());


            snake.HandleSnakeInput ();

            //Draw onto the screen
            SwinGame.RefreshScreen (60);


        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see from the codes, the game runs on a while loop. I was able to delay the method using "Task.Delay (1000).ContinueWith (t => snake.MoveForward ());" but only on the first loop. When i debug, the snake delays successfully on the first loop but zoom pasts the rest of the loops.

How can i implement the code so that at every loop the method is delayed so that the snake can move at a constant speed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You clear and redraw screen inside loop? That doesn't seem right

Comment: Instead of a while loop create a function and call it recursively from the `ContinueWith`. Or just wait for the result of the task by adding `Wait() ` after `ContinueWith`

Comment: There is NO reason to use `Task.Delay`. Use `System.Timers.Timer`. Move snake Inside callback. There is no need for while loop either

Comment: There are two primary approaches to game loop design: (1) measure time delta for each loop iteration and update movements relative to the amout of elapsed time. (2) synchronize time at a point in each iteration. Your approach (3) assume something about the time at each iteration is what makes some very old games unplayable, because the relation between computation time and waiting time is not generally predictable. (ofc. there may be other approaches in current game programming - i'm not completely up to date)

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a delayed task on every iteration of the loop. You're not actually delaying the loop you're just delaying the execution of the MoveForward method, so the loop still runs at maximum speed. This causes that after the initial delay tasks are executed at the same speed as the loop was run. To wait for a task to complete use `await`.

If you want the snake to move at a certain interval why not use a timer?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Elapsed += ( sender, e ) => snake.MoveForward();
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Actually, timer is fine, but it might be worth to mention, that he never actually `awaits` the delayed task and thats the source of the problem.

Comment: It's what I meant to say, though reading the answer again it wasn't very clear. I edited the answer and hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your method worked. The snake is now moving constantly and the can move in all direction.